# How to extend a converter in JSF 1.2

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

I don't like the way [`f:convertNumber`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/convertNumber.html) display NaN (`"\ufffd"`) and both of the infinities (`"\u221e"`).

Is there a way to extend the out-of-the-box converter in order to inject my own display logic? Thank you.

Comment: You could create your own converter. See [Creating a JSF 1.2 Custom Converter with Attributes](http://jerryorr.blogspot.com/2011/10/creating-jsf-12-custom-converter-with.html) and [Create simple custom Converter implementation class in JSF](http://www.javabeat.net/2008/07/create-simple-custom-converter-implementation-class-in-jsf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this:

1. Create a class that extends [NumberConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/convert/NumberConverter.html).
2. Override the [getAsString](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/convert/NumberConverter.html#getAsString%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.Object%29) method by explicitly handling your special values, and deferring to `super` for all others. Pseudocode:

   ```
   getAsString(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, Object value) {
       if (value is NaN) {
           return your-own-NaN-string;
       }

       if (value is infinity) {
           return your-own-infinity-string;
       }

       return super.getAsNumber(ctx, component, value);
   }
   ```
3. Register the class as a converter and use it instead of `f:convertNumber`.

Comment: Well, I was hoping for a better solution, since now I also have to deal with formatting and setting the correct locale. But I guess it's still worth accepting your answer. :) Thanks.

Comment: If you find a better solution, I'll definitely be happy to know.